match random lengths of string using regex (preg_match)
i have need to split string, by regex:

split digits together
split letters together
[ each part should contain between 3-5 chars RANDOMLY ]

so if i have:
'aaa555aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa55555555555555555'

so the result MIGHT be:
'aaa 555 aaa aaaa aaaaa aaaa aaa aaa 55555 555 555 555 555'

(the last item might be 1-2 characters length).
so i started with regex:
preg_match_all('/([a-z]+)|([0-9]+)/')

the question how to apply the random part. if it is possible... :)

Then do not use +, use limiting (range) quantifiers.

Just write as you say :) \d{3,5}|[a-z]{3,5} https://regex101.com/r/Ulr9SZ/1 What is that random thing?

yes, but this way it will give always 5 chars (if possible). i want randomly chosen, once 3 once 5 once 4 and so...    and this not capture the ending (aa + 55 in your code example)

Regex has no random generator. You can use regex with callback for doing that. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

this is what i'm doing at the moment: preg_match_all  and then,  run over the string, and split it manually every time RANDOM 3-5 chars.  but i search for nicer REGEX skills ;)

That is not a regex task. It is for matching PATTERNS not random things.
